# Getting all database names from within a SQL Server procedure using DBID?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a logging procedure that I am converting to use service broker. The procedure that performs the logging takes a database id, procedure id, and message as arguments. It converts the database id to database name and the procedure id to procedure name.

This works fine when I am executing this from within the database that holds the procedures, but from other databases it cannot convert the database id or the schema id and returns null instead. What do I need to do to make the following work, or what is an alternative?

```
SET @databaseName = COALESCE((SELECT name
                              FROM master.sys.databases
                              WHERE database_id = @databaseID),  
                             CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), @databaseId));

-- set dbname
-- SET @databaseName = COALESCE(DB_NAME(COALESCE(@databaseID, DB_ID())), convert( varchar(15),@databaseId));

SET @schemaName = COALESCE(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@objectID, @databaseID), CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), @objectID));

SET @procedureName = COALESCE(OBJECT_NAME(@objectID, @databaseID), 'UNDEFINED');
```

The entire procedure is as follows:

```
************************************************************************
--  Make  Direct Log Entry
--  Purpose:
--    Log information as requested by procedure consumer without further
--    processing
--  Arguments:
--    ObjectID       - object id of calling procedure, use @@procid
--    DatabaseID     - id of the database, leave null and DB_ID() will be used
--    message        - Message to be logged
--    printLabel     - label followed by message are printed if not null
--  Modified:
--    2022-04-08 - BFL Recreated
-- ************************************************************************

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mleDirect] 
    @databaseID INT = NULL,
    @objectID   INT,
    @message    NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @printLabel NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @procedureName SYSNAME;
    DECLARE @schemaName SYSNAME;
    DECLARE @databaseName SYSNAME;
    DECLARE @sessionid BIGINT;

    DECLARE @trace BIT = dbo.getDebug();

    EXEC getLogSessionID @sessionid OUTPUT;

    IF @databaseID IS NULL
        SET @databaseID = -1;

    IF @objectID IS NULL
        SET @objectID = -1;

    SET @databaseName = COALESCE((SELECT name
                                  FROM master.sys.databases
                                  WHERE database_id = @databaseID), CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), @databaseId));
    -- set dbname
    -- SET @databaseName = COALESCE(DB_NAME(COALESCE(@databaseID, DB_ID())), convert( varchar(15),@databaseId));
    SET @schemaName = COALESCE(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@objectID, @databaseID), CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), @objectID));

    SET @procedureName = COALESCE(OBJECT_NAME(@objectID, @databaseID), 'UNDEFINED');

    IF @trace = 1
    BEGIN
        PRINT '...';
        PRINT '[dbo].[mleDirect] arguments';
        PRINT N'Database Name : ' + @databaseName;
        PRINT N'Schema   Name : ' + @schemaName;
        PRINT N'Procedure Name: ' + @procedureName;
        PRINT N'Message       : ' + @message;
    END;

    BEGIN TRAN logit;
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[log] ([database], [schema], [procedure], [message], [sessionID])
        VALUES (@databaseName, @schemaName, @procedureName, @message, @sessionid);

        COMMIT TRAN logit;

        IF @printLabel IS NOT NULL
           PRINT '[mleDirect] ' + @printLabel + ' ' + @message;
  END;
```

Comment: unrelated: completely unnecessary explicit transaction. Also, the fact you have this logging procedure leads to suspect you have an XY problem

Comment: Why not just pass the schema name in addition to the object ID - and pass the object name instead as well (this is known to the calling object, after all), then you just insert it. And as noted, a single T-SQL statement is its own implicit transaction.

Comment: @Stu I have thought of passing the names as you stated. I am trying to minimize the required coding to use the logging. @@PROCID gets the procedure name w/o any calls, `decalre dbid int = db_id()` is all that is needed to get the database Id. Converting the two to text is minimal work, but it does add some more work that is repeated with each procedure that logs.

Answer (score 1):

Objective: get database name, schema name, object name from any database given a specific `@databaseID` and `@objectID`. Using the database ID allows us to execute dynamic SQL against the metadata in a given database (even if it's the current database):

```
-- simulate input params:
DECLARE @databaseID int = 5,
        @objectID int = 581577110;

-- local variables:
DECLARE @sql    nvarchar(max),
        @exec   nvarchar(256),
        @dbname sysname = DB_NAME(@databaseID),
        @schema sysname,
        @object sysname;

-- dynamic SQL:
SET @sql = N'SELECT @schema = s.name, @object = o.name
  FROM sys.objects AS o
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  WHERE o.[object_id] = @oID;';

-- set execution context:
SET @exec = QUOTENAME(@dbname) + N'.sys.sp_executesql';

-- run dynamic SQL using OUTPUT:
EXEC @exec @stmt = @sql, 
  @params = N'@oID int, @schema sysname OUTPUT, @object sysname OUTPUT', 
  @obj      = @oID, 
  @schema   = @schema OUTPUT, 
  @object   = @object OUTPUT;

SELECT @dbname, @schema, @object;
```

Though it's a seldom-used feature of functions like `OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME()` that they take an optional database ID as an argument, so you should be able to simplify to the following:

```
SELECT DB_NAME(@databaseID),
       OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@objectID, @databaseID),
       OBJECT_NAME(@objectID, @databaseID);
```

But the dynamic-SQL-in-database-context is a handy thing to have in your toolkit, because not all metadata functions work this way, and also because [those functions don't respect isolation semantics](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-metadata-helper-functions).

Comment: Thankyou for your response, but unforturnately it isn't working for me. `dbname sysname = DB_NAME(@databaseID)` returns null for other databases, I am running into the same problem I had before. I think I will just pass in the dbname and the proc name and be done with it. P.S. I apologize for the late response, my wife was injured in another state and I had to take care of her.

Comment: @BrianLeach db_name() would only return null if you passed in an invalid database id (are you sure it's not null? are you sure the database id isn't from a different instance)?

Comment: I need to do more research. I was creating a simple example for demonstration and it worked as you stated. Now I am really confused. (How do I put your name after the '@' so you are flagged in these comments?)

Comment: @BrianLeach I am the author of the post you're commenting on, so I get a notification automatically.